# Strange animation on inserting and deleting cells in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview

It seem that inserting and deleting cells in ios6 for UICollectionView works incorrectly. I tried making changes in `-finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:` and `initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:` and had no luck in solving the problem. I think the reason it didn't work I don't really get why UICollectionView behaves this way. The video of animation in ios7 is  [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vsus7xglqb9hsp4/video2.mov) (it is animation I expect). The way it looks on ios6 can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1zx33l1jwjh33m9/video.mov). Please, explain me or give a tip how to get rid of it. Thanks in advance.